# Filter records in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mojrG.jpg)I have a table with 3 columns Id,Unit and Process:

```
|Id  |Unit  |Process   |
|----|------|----------|
|100 |1     |0         |
|100 |0     |5         |
|101 |1     |0         |
```

Output

```
|Id  |Unit  |Process   |
|----|------|----------|
|101 |1     |0         |
```

---

I want to exclude all ID's which have process value as 5.

So ID 100 has a process 5, so all rows for ID 100 will be removed
Also I want addtional conditions all records should have unit value as 1 in output set.

Here what I tried but I need short query

```
Select id,unit, process from table a where id in
(
Select distinct id from table a where unit=1
)
And id not in
(
Select distinct id from table a where process=5
)
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Here what i tried but i need short query 
Select id,unit, process from table a where id in
(
Select distinct id from table a where unit=1
)
And id not in
(
Select distinct id from table a where process=5
)

Comment: That "sample" data is impossible consume. Tabular formatted `text` would be vastly better. As for your question, what have you tried, why didn't it work? What are your expected results?

Comment: I get my result but i want a better way

Comment: Actually in real scenario I have base query built using several joins, and i had to copy and paste that base query gain in subqueries. Can't it be done using joins somehow.

Comment: How? Please guide me

Comment: Does `id` not *identify* the record?  Wouldn't you get the same results from: `select id, unit, process from a where unit = 1 and process <> 5`

Comment: But in that case the top row of my image which I have shared will be in my output set, but I don't want that. I want to exclude all rows which have id which has process value as 5

Comment: @HrishikeshBagchi: Instead of taking pictures of your notebook, please include in the question the actual table structures and sample data, as well as a sample of the intended results.

Comment: For some reason, comments won't allow me to post my solution, nor an answer. David provided what I was going to suggest. It would allow you to remove that last line.

Comment: What David suggested, will remove the record with process value of 5 (only 1 row with id 100) but the another row of id 100 will be present in my result set, and i don't want that in my result ser

Comment: I just updated the image with queries suggested and actual output needed

Comment: Don't. Use. Images.  Edit your question to include tables of sample source data and desired results.

Comment: Please don't take pictures! Never take a picture of your monitor! It's a pet peeve for most people in IT.

Comment: Sorry for pictures, I edited my question. Please have a look at my actual dataset and the needed output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Data set up:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Id      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Unit    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Process INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Id,Unit,Process) VALUES (100,1,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(Id,Unit,Process) VALUES (100,0,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(Id,Unit,Process) VALUES (101,1,0);
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM mytable AS m1
WHERE 
  m1.Unit = 1
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM mytable AS m2 
              WHERE m1.ID = m2.ID AND m2.Process = 5);
```

Results:

```
+-----+------+---------+
| Id  | Unit | Process |
+-----+------+---------+
| 101 |   1  |       0 |
+-----+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS and not EXISTS, this way, you will be able to return all the records for the successful IDs:

```
;with tableA as
(select 100 as id,1 as unit,5 as Process union
select 100,0,5 union
select 101,1,0)

Select * from tableA a
where EXISTS
      (Select 1 from tableA b where a.id=b.id and b.unit=1) 
      AND NOT EXISTS
      (Select 1 from tableA c where a.id=c.id and c.process=5)
```